# How do the JsHelper Request success/error/complete callbacks work in CakePHP 2.1?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, cakephp, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to set up an invitation request page using the CakePHP 2.1 framework, jQuery, and Cake's JsHelper in order to submit the users email and then issue a response.  Ideally, I would like to have the form fade out after the email is successfully submitted, unfortunately when use the "success" or "complete" callbacks, it fades out even when it hits a validation error.

My view.ctp code:

```
<?php $this->Js->get('#InvitationRequestAddForm'); ?>
    <?php $this->Js->event(
        'submit',
        $this->Js->request(
            array(
                    'controller'=>'InvitationRequests',
                    'action'=>'add'
            ),
            array('async' => true,
                'method' => 'POST',
                'dataExpression'=>true,
                'update' => '#invitationStatus',
                'complete' => "$('#InvitationRequestAddForm').fadeOut();",
                'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(
                    array(
                        'isForm' => true,
                        'inline' => true
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ); ?>
```

My controller code:

```
if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) 
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) 
        {
            $this->InvitationRequest->create();
            if ($this->InvitationRequest->save($this->request->data)) 
            {
                $this->set('alert_state', 'alert-success');
                $this->set('message', '<strong>Hang Tight!</strong> We have your request and we are working hard to approve as soon as possible!');
            } 
            else 
            {
                $this->set('alert_state', 'alert-error');
                $this->set('message', '<strong>Uh Oh!</strong> Something went wrong, check your email address and please try again.');
            }
        } 
    }
```

Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) specify this for the `complete` option in jquery

> A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed).

So, whether it be success or error it gets called anyway. You need to change that `complete` with `success` and (if you want (but recommended)) `error` to execute the fadeOut you want, because `complete` will always execute after an ajax call.

Now, another thing. You have to keep in mind that even if the `save` in the controller has validation errors and does not save, the ajax call will be succesfull. Why? Because the conection with the action will be ok and there's no awful errors in the controller. So, in the `success` function of the ajax call, you need to check the `alert-state` variable and if it is `alert-success`, do the fadeOut, otherwise handle the error as you wish.

Comment: Thanks Nunser!  That's what I thought was going on but I couldn't find the documentation (I was looking in the Cake Docs, I should have known).